# Showing websites full HTML code

Tags: html, parsing, url, jsoup

I'm trying to parse a html code for specific content, but the problem I'm running into is that certain websites require you to click a "Show more" button.

When I grab the URL there's no way to tell it I want the full code with the "Show more" button clicked. Is there a way to grab the full source code of the page, because it keeps getting cut off after a point.

Example website: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=fm%20radio&c=apps&hl=en

The source code gets cut off at the "Radio hungary" app, which is the last app that loads automatically.

This even happens when I load everything and then try to view the pages source code.

It ends in:

```
style="display:none"> Show More </button> <div class="bottom-loading" style="display:none"></div> <div class="footer"> <div class="footer-links-container"> <span class="copyright"> ©2016 Google</span> <a class="footer-link id-no-nav" href="https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/about/play-terms.html" target="_blank"> Site Terms of Service</a> <a class="footer-link id-no-nav" href="http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/policies/privacy/" target="_blank"> Privacy Policy</a>  <a class="footer-link id-no-nav" href="http://developer.android.com/index.html" target="_blank"> Developers</a> <a class="footer-link id-no-nav" href="https://play.google.com/artists" target="_blank"> Artists</a>  <a class="footer-link id-no-nav" href="https://support.google.com/googleplay/?p=about_play" target="_blank"> About Google</a>   </div>  </div> </div></div><div class="loading" jscontroller="EgJAl" jsaction="rcuQ6b:rcuQ6b" id="page-load-indicator"></div><div id="instrument-manager-parent"></div><script src="https://wallet.google.com/inapp/lib/buy.js"></script><script
```

Even if I click the show more button.
The purpose of this is to grab all the URL's of the images, and I can't do this by hand because well.. we have thousands of images.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you just take advantage of the Javascript HTML DOM methods you can accomplish what you want to achieve.

This will help: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_methods.asp

By using this, you can target specific elements/ids/classes and pull or modify the information you want.
Jquery will also help you a lot with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using Javascript dom,steps to do are

- keep your content in a div element
- set its default height as a fixed value
- on clicking the show more link execute a javascript function to make the div element height to auto

in this way you can show content excerpt with javascript

If you go for server side, you can create a new page for showing the content.